# Which base Ubuntu 14.04 AMI to choose for creating a custom Ubuntu AMI?

Tags: 14.04, server, amazon-ec2, aws

There are a bunch of new AMIs created frequently and made available in EC2 by Canonical:

[image: Ubuntu AMIs]

Is it encouraged to use these AMIs for creating custom Ubuntu AMIs, or is it recommended to use the [official Ubuntu 14.04 AMI in the Market Place](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00JV9TBA6/ref=mkt_wir_Ubuntu14)?

Also is there an official Ubuntu 14.04.2 AMI created and made available by Canonical? I've searched but couldn't find any.